# Remove unnecessary dependencies in a task graph?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

I'm modeling a game tech/build tree as a directed acyclic graph with a .dot file for visualization use in Graphviz.

Some of the dependencies discovered are redundant in the sense that while they are dependencies, they are satisfied via a longer yet required path.

```
a -> b 
b -> c
a -> c // Unnecessary because we have to do b first.
```

And a longer example

```
a -> b
b -> c
c -> d
a -> d // Unnecessary between we have to do both b and c first.
```

Is there an algorithm to testing a graph for these unnecessary paths so that I could trim them from the .dot file?  Perhaps this is more appropriately a programming question, but I'm guessing some use of graph theory applies here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT, what you want is called a [transitive reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_reduction) of the graph.  La Wik claims that Graphviz can do the job somehow; consult its documentation.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, Graphviz contains a filter called tred that does the transitive reduction.

Now off to understand the math behind it.

Answer (score 0):

For each vertex x, make a set that contain each vertex y that can reach x. This sets also includes x.

If you have two edges b -> a and c -> a, then if the set associated with b is a subset of the set associated with c, then the edge b -> a can be removed.

Example:

a -> b
 
b -> c
a -> c

The set are:
a:  { a }
b:  { a, b }  // Can be reached from a and b
c:  { a, b, c}

If you look at the edges:
b -> c
a -> c

Then you see that the set of a is a subset of b. So, the edge a -> c can be removed.

Lucas